# openldap new version , change of configuration method

Tags: openldap

I just read the below openldap official URL , it indicate that new version do not use slapd.conf for configuration , it should use cn=config .

```
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html
```

I just would like to confirm if I setup new openldap version 2.4 , I should no longer use slapd.conf , is that right ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> it indicate that new version do not use slapd.conf for configuration

No it doesn't.

From the link you posted, *verbatim:*

> The older style *slapd.conf(5)* file is still supported

Comment: thanks reply , if slapd.conf(5) file is still supported , if I use new version of openldap ,  which method cn=config or slapd.conf should use ?                                                                                                            thanks

Comment: Whichever you prefer. I would start with *slapd.conf* until you have a stable configuration you're comfortable with, then convert it.

Comment: thanks reply , but what you mean "then convert it" use slapd.conf first , then convert it to second method ? which one is better ? thanks